# Does clearing one's Google Drive old photo files also remove photos in Google Photos?

Tags: synchronization, google-drive, google-photos

Way back when Google Drive was synced with Google Photos - i.e. I've had my photos backed up to Drive with Google Backup & Sync, and they'd automatically show up in Google Photos. I need to free up some space on Google Drive now - would deleting the original photos on there also remove them from Google Photos, or is Google Photos collection been copied there, now independent of the original Google Drive files?

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer. Apparently because the relationship between the two products was confusing, starting in July 2019 Google decided to separate them so that:

> [When you upload or delete photos in Google Drive or Google Photos, changes  won’t reflect in the other product](https://support.google.com/photos/answer/9316089?p=blogpost_transitionarticle&visit_id=636957989726780274-3529170745&rd=1)